# Find out which mail server is installed on Ubuntu

Tags: email, ubuntu, mail-server

I have access to a couple of Ubuntu servers and I am trying to configure the PHP mail() command for each of these servers. However, for one of these servers, the From: header is overwritten by www-data@. I have no access to the SPF record of that hostname, so I want to configure the mail server so it doesn't overwrite the From: header.

So my question is, how do I find out which mail server is used so I can correctly configure that mail server? (Postfix, SSMTP, ...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a list of packages installed locally do this in your terminal:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

To save that list to a text file called packages on your desktop do this in your terminal:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

Then search for Mailserver. I'll do my bet for Postfix, which seems to be the most used.

Credit goes [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Answer (score 2):

Finding which server is listening on port 25 may help (expecially if you have multiple MTA installed but only one which one is running).

```
(sudo) netstat -tanp | grep ':25'
```

As Following suggested, you need to be root (sudo).

You will get the PID of the process, for example :

```
tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:25  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 98249/master
```

Here I found the PID (98249 in my case), and you can get more information with ps or lsof

```
ps 98249
lsof -p 98249
```

Comment: ```$ netstat -tanp | grep ':25'
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      - 
```

This doesn't seem to show which MTA was installed.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment, you may need `sudo` `$ sudo netstat -tanp | grep ':25'`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      91245/master 
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      91245/master 
```

In this case, `sudo postfix status` also help to confirm that I am running `postfix` as a mail transfer agent.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mail



rc  libc-client2007e                      8:2007f~dfsg-4                                           amd64        c-client library for mail protocols - library files
ii  libmail-sendmail-perl                 0.79.16-1                                                all          Send email from a perl script
ii  libmailtools-perl                     2.13-1                                                   all          Manipulate email in perl programs
ii  libmailutils4:amd64                   1:2.99.99-1ubuntu2                                       amd64        GNU Mail abstraction library
ii  mailutils                             1:2.99.99-1ubuntu2                                       amd64        GNU mailutils utilities for handling mail
ii  mailutils-common                      1:2.99.99-1ubuntu2                                       all          Common files for GNU mailutils
ii  mime-support                          3.59ubuntu1                                              all          MIME files 'mime.types' & 'mailcap', and support programs
ii  postfix                               3.1.0-3ubuntu0.3                                         amd64        High-performance mail transport agent
```